# module_error and session timeout

Tags: amazon-ec2, instance

```
 errorMessage: Unable to import module 'langchain-aws-template-main.service.lambda_function': No module named 'config',
```

.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f5109ecd610>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused  ,

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.